# Prove via Strong Induction: $n$-th Fibonacci number is $\frac{\varphi^n-\rho^n}{\varphi-\rho}$, where $\varphi$ & $\rho$ are the roots of $x^2-x+1=0$.

Tags: proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $f_n$ denote the $n$th Fibonacci number i.e. $f_1=f_2= 1$ and $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
>   Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f_n=\frac{\varphi^n - \rho^n}{\varphi- \rho}$, where $\varphi$ and $\rho$ are the two solutions of the quadratic equation given by
>   $x^2−x+ 1 = 0$.

I need to use strong induction.  What I have is that $f_{n+1}=f_{n-1}+f_n$. From my inductive hypothesis I know what $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n}$ equal. Is that the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to do the arithmetic to prove that
$$f_n+f_{n-1}=\frac{\varphi^n - \rho^n}{\varphi- \rho} 
    + \frac{\varphi^{n-1} - \rho^{n-1}}{\varphi- \rho}
   = f_{n+1}.$$
In fact $\varphi^n+\varphi^{n-1} = \varphi^{n+1}$ and similarly for $\rho$. Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to note that both $\varphi$ and $\rho$ satisfy $x-1 = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: so do i have to plug in the actual solutions of the quadratic equation into fn and fn-1?

Comment: Not really. It suffices to show that $\varphi^n+\varphi^{n-1} = \varphi^{n+1}$ (and similarly for $\rho$). But the LHS is $\varphi^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{\varphi}\right)$. If you use the fact I stated above (after convincing yourself that it's true, of course), the result falls out.

Comment: where are you getting the LHS from?

Comment: Just factor $\varphi^n+\varphi^{n-1}$.